# How to add feature or thumbnail image for post in .Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm currently trying to setup a hugo blog with blogdown and can't find a way to add feature or thumbnail images to posts from within `.Rmd` files, which would like this with the [tranquilpeak theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/):

[image: feature_image]

As far as I understand, it is easy to do in .md files by just adding some syntax like this:

```
+++
featuredImage = "img/foobar.jpg"
+++
```

I found this in the [minos theme](https://github.com/carsonip/hugo-theme-minos) and in a [discourse post](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/post-featured-image/864). But how can I do this inside a `.Rmd` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter whether you use .md or .Rmd: if the theme supports the `featuredImage` option, you can also use it in .Rmd. The only thing you need to make sure is to write metadata in YAML instead of TOML if the post format is .Rmd ([see documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html)), i.e.,

```
---
featuredImage: "img/foobar.jpg"
---
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the `.Rmd` filename to `index.Rmd` and use the `featured.png/jpg` image in the page's folder.

Works fine for me.